# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined - google.maps is undefined (React)

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I'm having an error while using google maps js API, every few loads I'm getting this error.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined
(anonymous function)
src/features/landingPage/components/LandingPageMap.js:10

The Map Component

```
const LandingPageMap = (props) => {
const { center, zoom, reports } = props;
const mapRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
   const map = new window.google.maps.Map(mapRef.current, {
    center: center,
    zoom: zoom,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
  });
 }, [center, zoom, reports]);

return (
 <>
   <div
    ref={mapRef}
    className={`map ${props.className}`}
    style={props.style}
  >
    Loading map...
  </div>
</>
 );
};

  export default LandingPageMap;
```

I'm getting the Google map API in the index.html file inside the head tag.

```
 <script async
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLE-MAPS-API-KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
 </script>
```

I'm not sure how to solve this problem. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: You can always check that `window.google` exists before trying to use it.  `if (window.google) { //do stuff }`  This will prevent fatal errors, but you might not always have a map.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I tried but unfortunately, it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using frameworks, loading the Maps Javascript API is not as simple as putting it in the `index.html` unlike in vanilla javascript. One way to do this and not rely on 3rd party libraries is to instead load the script dynamically in the map component.

Here is a simple working sample for your reference or see below for the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-simple-map-ek1igt

**App.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import Map from './components/map';
    import "./style.css";
    
    class App extends Component {
     
      render() {
        return (
           <Map 
            id="myMap"
            options={{
              center: { lat: -33.8569, lng: 151.2152 },
              zoom: 8
            }}
          />
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default App;
```

**map.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    
    class Map extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }
    
      onScriptLoad() {
        const map = new window.google.maps.Map(
          document.getElementById(this.props.id),
          this.props.options);
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        if (!window.google) {
          var s = document.createElement('script');
          s.type = 'text/javascript';
          s.src = `https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY`;
          var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
          // Below is important. 
          //We cannot access google.maps until it's finished loading
          s.addEventListener('load', e => {
            this.onScriptLoad()
          })
        } else {
          this.onScriptLoad()
        }
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="map" id={this.props.id} />
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default Map
```